# Updating Strings with CHRTRAN Visual FoxPro function

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have some basic record keeping software; we are trying to capture email addresses, supporting software cannot capture an '@' sign.

Trying to use Visual FoxPro command CHRTRAN to search the field 'UdidText' for a comma ',' and replace it with an '@' sign.

The current code snippet reads:

```
update [udids] set udidtext = CHRTRAN (udidtext, '%,%', '@') where udidno = '78' and udidtext != ''
```

As a brief note; the percent sign is my preferred wildcard.

Edit: When checking the code in my application, the function produces an error "Operator/operand type mismatch".

Answer (score 2):

CHRTRAN() doesn't need or want the wildcards. The second parameter is the character or characters to replace. So try:

```
CHRTRAN(uiditext, ',', '@')
```

Tamar

Answer (score 0):

As per the chrtran() part, it would simply be:

```
chrtran(uidtext, ',', '@')
```

Your code is likely giving you error because udidno is not character? Probably you need:

```
 .. udidno = 78 ...
```

there.

However your code wouldn't do any replacement at all, unless ANSI is ON. You have this:

```
... and udidtext != ''
```

If ANSI is NOT ON then that part would resolve to FALSE and no update would occur. To correct it you need, either SET ANSI ON or better use == which is ANSI free:

```
update [udids] set udidtext = CHRTRAN(udidtext, ',', '@') where udidno = '78' and !(udidtext == '')
```

In the same manner = '78' would mean any records where udidno Starts With '78'. If you need an exact match there, then that would become:

```
update [udids] set udidtext = CHRTRAN(udidtext, ',', '@') where udidno == '78' and !(udidtext == '')
```

Last part is actually unnecessary, so it becomes:

```
update [udids] set udidtext = CHRTRAN(udidtext, ',', '@') where udidno == '78'
```

And finally, your udidno might be a numeric:

```
update [udids] set udidtext = CHRTRAN(udidtext, ',', '@') where udidno = 78
```